# How to stop a simulation in contiki with script when all motes(nodes) have a certain output?

Tags: javascript, contiki

This code would stop the simulation when one node(no matter which one) print 'ok'.

```
WAIT_UNTIL(msg.equals('ok'));
log.testOK();
```

This code means node 1 print 'ok', then stop.

```
WAIT_UNTIL(id == 1 && msg.equals("ok"));
log.testOK();
```

I want to stop the simulation when all nodes already print 'ok', means after each node prints 'ok' at least one time. I tried some codes but it didn't work.

Not work(every node already print ok, not stop) code(suppose I have 10 nodes):

```
var test = 0;
for (var i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    if (id == i && msg.equals("ok")){
        test = test+1;
        }
}
WAIT_UNTIL(test == 10);
log.testOK();
```

Not work(every node already print ok, not stop) either:

```
WAIT_UNTIL((id == 1 && msg.equals("ok"))&&(id == 2 && msg.equals("ok")....(id == 10 && msg.qeuals("ok"));
log.testOK();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance. It's better if I don't need to specify the total node number in script.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until your condition is true. Once true then call stopSimulation() function of the Simulation class.

```
/* Stops this simulation (notifies observers). */ 
public void stopSimulation() 
{ 
    if (isRunning())
     { 
        stopSimulation = true; 
        /* Wait until simulation stops */ 
        if (Thread.currentThread() != simulationThread) 
           { 
            try 
               { 
                if (simulationThread != null) 

                   { 
                     simulationThread.join(); 
                    } 
               } 
                 catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    { 
                    } 
               } 
         }
    }
```